# How to expose multiple list models in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model that takes smaller models as lists:

```
  public class MostPlayedList
{
    public IList<MostPlayed> mostPlayed = new List<MostPlayed>();
    public IList<SongNominator> songNominator = new List<SongNominator>();
    public IList<MostUpvoted> songsUpvoted = new List<MostUpvoted>();
    public IList<MostUpvoting> userUpvoting = new List<MostUpvoting>();
}
```

The other models are hybrid viewmodels that contain information relevant for the view. Now I fill these lists up in the control using the example below:

```
 MostPlayedList s = new MostPlayedList();
var mostPlayed = db.Songs.OrderBy(n => n.timesPlayed).ToList().Take(5);
```

Then for each item found, I add to the IList, in this case the `MostPlayed` IList:

```
 //most played songs
        foreach (var item in mostPlayed)
        {
            s.mostPlayed.Add(new MostPlayed() { name = item.name, timePlayed = item.timesPlayed });
        }
```

I do this for the other list items, then pass it into the partial view like so:

```
 return PartialView(s);
```

The problem I'm having is on the view, how do I drill down and expose the relevant list items? I tried using this in the partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<JayVumic.Models.MostPlayedList>
```

And then using for each:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.) {
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, what would be the best way to expose this model and loop through the data of a given IList?

Comment: maybe you should use `@model JayVumic.Models.MostPlayedList` and iterate it using `@foreach (var item in Model.mostPlayed)` cause you passing single MostPlayedList object to view, not an enumerable

Comment: Dmitry would be right...and if that's the case, QED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat each list individually you should do what Dmitry suggested in a comment. Create 4 foreach loops and display what has to be displayed for each collection.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.mostPlayed ) {
...
}
@foreach (var item in Model.songNominator ) {
...
}
@foreach (var item in Model.songsUpvoted ) {
...
}
@foreach (var item in Model.userUpvoting ) {
...
}
```

However if your smaller models share the same part, and you want to treat them alike, (**it seems they don't, but think of it as an interesting fact for the future**) you can extract a common interface from them. Than you can make MostPlayedList implement IEnumerable and return concated lists. Than you could use only one foreach loop on Model.

```
public class MostPlayedList : IEnumerable<YourCommonInteface>
{
    public IList<MostPlayed> mostPlayed = new List<MostPlayed>();
    public IList<SongNominator> songNominator = new List<SongNominator>();
    public IList<MostUpvoted> songsUpvoted = new List<MostUpvoted>();
    public IList<MostUpvoting> userUpvoting = new List<MostUpvoting>();

    public IEnumerator<YourCommonInteface> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return mostPlayed.Concat(songNominator).Concat(songsUpvoted).Concat();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the ticket for me.